# HTTPRoute set a timeout

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, websocket, timeout, api-gateway

I am trying to set up a multi-cluster architecture. I have a Spring Boot API that I want to run on a second cluster (for isolation purposes). I have set that up using the `gateway.networking.k8s.io` API. I am using a `Gateway` that has an SSL certificate and matches an IP address that's registered to my domain in the DNS registry. I am then setting up an HTTPRoute for each service that I am running on the second cluster. That works fine and I can communicate between our clusters and everything works as intended but there is a problem:

There is a `timeout` of 30s by default and I cannot change it. I want to increase it as the application in the second cluster is a WebSocket and I obviously would like our WebSocket connections to stay open for more than 30s at a time. I can see that in the backend service that's created from our HTTPRoute there is a timeout specified as 30s. I found a command to increase it `gcloud compute backend-services update gkemcg1-namespace-store-west-1-8080-o1v5o5p1285j --timeout=86400`

When I run that command it would increase the timeout and the webSocket connection will be kept alive. But after a few minutes this change gets overridden (I suspect that it's because it's managed by the yaml file). This is the yaml file for my backend service

```
kind: HTTPRoute
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: public-store-route
  namespace: namespace
  labels:
    gateway: external-http
spec:
  hostnames:
  - "my-website.example.org"
  parentRefs:
  - name: external-http
  rules:
  - matches:
    - path:
        type: PathPrefix
        value: /west
    backendRefs:
    - group: net.gke.io
      kind: ServiceImport
      name: store-west-1
      port: 8080
```

I have tried to add either a `timeout`, `timeoutSec`, or `timeoutSeconds` under every level with no success. I always get the following error:

`error: error validating "public-store-route.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(HTTPRoute.spec.rules[0].backendRefs[0]): unknown field "timeout" in io.k8s.networking.gateway.v1beta1.HTTPRoute.spec.rules.backendRefs; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

Surely there must be a way to configure this. But I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation referring to a timeout. Am I missing something here?

How do I configure the timeout?

Edit:

I have found this resource: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-gateway-resources

I have been trying to set up a LBPolicy and attatch it it the Gateway, HTTPRoute, Service, or ServiceImport but nothing has made a difference. Am I doing something wrong or is this not working how it is supposed to? This is my yaml:

```
kind: LBPolicy
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
metadata:
  name: store-timeout-policy
  namespace: sandstone-test
spec:
  default:
    timeoutSec: 50
  targetRef:
    name: public-store-route
    group: gateway.networking.k8s.io
    kind: HTTPRoute
```

Comment: what is the server you are using? e.g. if you are using gunicorn its default timeout is 30 seconds

Comment: @rossco I have solved it (kind of). I contacted the dev team at Google and apparently, this was not an expected behavior. I changed the Gateway class to the new still-in-development class gke-l7-global-external-managed-mc and that fixed my WebSocket dropouts. I still didn't manage to configure the timeouts but my problem was now gone. Ultimately I decided not to use this approach as it is still under development and some of the features I need from an LB weren't supported.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue , adding GCPBackendPolicy solve it.

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: GCPBackendPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-policy
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  default:
    timeoutSec: 50
  targetRef:
    group: "gateway.networking.k8s.io"
    kind: Service
    name: my-service
```